# Flush the DNS on mobile

Tags: settings, internet

Is there a way to flush DNS like we do on windows PC. Actually, deleting history is a pain and again entering all the credentials and setting cookie is tough.

The reason i need to flush DNS is because we migrated the website and i can't see it propogate on my mobile

Comment: Of course, none of your customers will know they need to flush DNS to carry on using your site...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this cannot be done on Windows Phone 7. If you are using Wi-Fi you could unplug your router+modem for 60 seconds and then try again. Depending on the brand, your router may have additional options to flush the DNS.